# Or statement in PHP

Tags: php

I want to add an ID to a span element if the page is either 'a' or 'b'.

My code so far is this:

```
<span class="subnav2" <? if(($page == 'a') || ($page == 'b')): ?> id="active"<? endif ?>>
```

but it only adds the class to the span when 'a' is true. What am I doing wrong?

The value of $page is:

```
<? 
    $path = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $page = basename($path);
    $page = basename($path, '.php');
    $page = str_replace('_',' ',$page);
    $page = str_replace('.php','',$page);
    $page = ucfirst($page);
?>
```

Comment: It should work. What value is `$page`?

Comment: I wonder if I'm doing it wrong.. it works for me, I tested with `$page` being set to a then to b..

Comment: I think 'a' will alllways be 'a'.

Comment: It is something to do with the value of $page but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Your value of short_open_tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :
 code:

```
<span class="subnav2" <? if(($page == 'a') || ($page == 'b')): echo "id=\"active\"" endif ?>>
```

Comment: Solved the syntax error:<span class="subnav2" <? if(($page == 'Origins of savannas') || ($page == 'About savannas of French Guiana')): echo "id=\"active\"" ?> <? endif ?>> but it still only works for the first page. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As you [may notice](http://phpguide.co.il/phplive?code=217), the code works even when `$page = 'b'`. The problem hides somewhere else, where $page is assigned. 
In either case, your code will look better this way:

```
<span class="subnav2" <?= $page == 'a' || $page == 'b' ? 'id="active"' : '' ?>>
```

Comment: Press the V image to accept an answer you'd like
whenever you ask a question and get it answered :)

Comment: missing a quote around `'id="active"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php if ($page == 'a' || $page == 'b'): ?>
```